# Performance: list all keys from hdf5 file with pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, hdf5, pytables

Is it normal that that it takes so long to obtain all present keys in a hdf5 file?

Code Sample:

```
start = time.time()
store = pd.HDFStore(filepath)
print(time.time() - start)
0.0

start = time.time()
a = store.keys()
print(time.time() - start)
23.874846696853638

len(a) 
80

start = time.time()
store.select(key="/data/table1") # the next table would be /data/table2
print(time.time() - start)

0.062399864196777344
```

All keys are 'tables' (i.e. not fixed). 
There are about 80 keys present in the file.

The entire size of the  `.h5` file is 348 MB. Each table has approx. the same size (after loading to a pandas.DataFrame) of 2.6 MB.

pandas v.0.20.1

tables v.3.2.2.

I am wondering if the key hierarchy is an issue: all in `data/table[X]` instead of directly into `table[X]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue.  It appears the cause is related to the way tables checks every single node value to create a list of keys.  I've raised this to pandas dev.

If you want to check whether a key is in the store then

```
store.__contains__(key)
```

will do the job and is much faster.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17593